# Issue with bootstrap 3 buttons not having space between them when appended to the page after page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where I have a simple test page, with 6 buttons.  There are declared in the body of the page, and 3 are added after the page loads, using jquery.
The 3 that get appended with jquery, do not have the spacing between then that the 3 that were declared in the page before it loaded do.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/c5QRS/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap Test Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>Buttons In Page</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div id="DynamicButtonContainer">
        <div>Buttons Dynamically Added</div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var eDynamicButtonContainer = $('#DynamicButtonContainer');
            eDynamicButtonContainer.append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>' + 
                                             '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>' + 
                                             '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>'));
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

How can I resolve this issue and get appended buttons to show with the same spacing as the ones that were declared in the page before load?

Thank you for your time,

Regards,

Scott

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728389/issue-with-bootstrap-3-buttons-not-having-space-between-them-when-appended-to-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons in your markup have whitespace between them in the markup (the newline and spaces/tabs for indentation), but the buttons in the markup you're appending don't, which is why they don't have space between them when rendered. If you add `\n` between them, that's whitespace, and spaces them out. Like this: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5QRS/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var eDynamicButtonContainer = $('#DynamicButtonContainer');
    eDynamicButtonContainer.append(
        $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>\n' +
        // Note -----------------------------------------------------^^ 
          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>\n' +
        // And -------------------------------------------------------^^
          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, and creating the updated fiddle, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c5QRS/2/

It's because of blank space between the tags. You concatenate with `\n` simulating the blank space and there you go.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, and creating the updated fiddle, much appreciated!!