# Horizontal space between bootstrap buttons using mithril.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mithril.js

When using pure bootstrap there is a small horizontal space between buttons.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This space disappears if elements are created with mithril.js:

```
var my = {};
my.view = function() {
  return m('.container-fluid', 
    m('.row',
      m('.col-xs-12', [
    m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Save'),
    m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Cancel')
      ])
    )
  );
};
m.mount(document.body, my);
```

What causes bootstrap to add small space between buttons? How to reproduce that in mithril.js?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728389/issue-with-bootstrap-3-buttons-not-having-space-between-them-when-appended-to-th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems line-end or space in HTML causes that small horizontal space between buttons. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008212/space-between-bootstrap-3-buttons) for similar question. To fix the issue in mithril.js I just added space between buttons:

```
var my = {};
my.view = function() {
  return m('.container-fluid', 
    m('.row',
      m('.col-xs-12', [
    m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Save'),
    ' ',
    m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Cancel')
      ])
    )
  );
};
m.mount(document.body, my);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, one of the big pains I regularly encountered when writing HTML templates was trying to eliminate whitespace. With Mithril, there is no whitespace. I wrote this little function to help me write templates where I expect gaps:

```
function gaps(){
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call( arguments, 
        function intersperse( output, item, index ){
            return Array.prototype.concat.call( output, ' ', item )
        } 
    )
}
```

So your code would become:

```
var my = {};
my.view = function() {
  return m('.container-fluid', 
    m('.row',
      m('.col-xs-12', gaps(
        m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Save'),
        m('button.btn.btn-default', 'Cancel')
      ))
    )
  );
};
m.mount(document.body, my);
```